# How to use class insted of id in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I want to use class instead of id in the following script....
i want a list of mp3 each have their corresponding button but when i click on any play button its play the first one mp3.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>       
    <body>
        <button onclick="playVid()" type="button">Play</button>
        <audio controls id="video1" style="display: none;">
            <source src="http://localhost/astrorecords/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/280.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        </audio>
        <script>
            var myVideo=document.getElementById("video1");
            function playVid() { 
                myVideo.play();
                var obj = document.getElementById("video1"); 
                if (obj) { 
                    obj.style.display='block'; 
                } 
             }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The solution your looking for cannot be achieved by querying for class, what you are more interested in is context and which element was acted upon (clicked).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)** instead of `document.getElementById()`:

```
var myVideo = document.getElementsByClassName("video1")[0];

function playVid() {
    myVideo.play();
    var obj = document.getElementsByClassName("video1")[0];
    if (obj) {
        obj.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zr9Vr/)**

Comment: hi thanks! for reply..... I want to add a list of mp3 and play button to each mp3 its still play the first one mp3 only any help please

Answer (score 0):

You should use the on click's event object and the target property (the DOM element you just clicked). Example:

```
function playVid(event) {
    var myVideo = event.target.nextSibling;
    myVideo.play();
    myVideo.style.display = 'block';
};
```

You'll most likely need to loop over all the  elements and hide them before you show the current one.

Good luck.